# Windows Defender won't install on Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-defender

I'm trying to install Windows Defender on one of our WIN Server 2016s but am getting a failure message with error code 0x800f0831. I tried the install through Server Manager > Add Roles and Feature.

Defender was removed from this server several months ago and now it needs to be reinstalled. Upon checking the CBS log, I saw entries regarding a missing package for KB5014702. However, upon trying to install that KB, I got a message stating that the KB was not applicable.

When looking at the list of installed Windows updates, I couldn't find that KB so that I could uninstall it and try a reinstall. So I'm at a deadend at the moment and was hoping someone here had any tips to share. Would be greatly appreciated!

Its important to note that our servers are "air gapped" (i.e. no Internet connectivity). So the DISM tool won't work for us to get us the packages the server needs.

Here's the entries in the CBS log:

2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Store corruption, manifest missing for package: Package_3201_for_KB5014702~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.73
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Error CBS    Failed to resolve package 'Package_3201_for_KB5014702~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.73' [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Mark store corruption flag because of package: Package_3201_for_KB5014702~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.73. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Failed to resolve package [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Failed to check whether this is the real child: Package_3201_for_KB5014702~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.73 [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Failed to collect affected dependent package for package: Windows-Defender-Management-Group-amcore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0 [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Failed to process package watchlist. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    Failed to plan execution. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Error CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x800f0831 - CBS_E_STORE_CORRUPTION]
2022-12-01 12:02:35, Info CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0, status: 0x800f0831, failure source: CBS Other, start state: Installed, target state: Installed, client id: DISM Package Manager Provider